# Accessing another method inside the self-executing function

Tags: javascript

Let's assume that I define a self-executing function like the following :

```
({
    function1: function(){//...}
    function2: function(){//...}
})
```

How can I call function2 from inside function1 ?

(I tried calling it just like : function2(); and this.function2(); , none worked, both returned error : function2() or this.function2() is not a function)

Actually this is part of the Aura framework, so maybe it is specific to this framework.

Comment: This is not not a self-executing function. It's not even a function.

Comment: In what way did it not work?  How are you calling these functions to test?

Comment: edited the question. "..." is not a function

Comment: This is a syntax error. Even if you used `/*...*/` to avoid commenting the `}` and added `,`, it would produce an object which wouldn't be stored anywhere, so you wouldn't be able to access it.

Comment: Ok, any idea on solution? the function is there, but it looks like that we don't have access to it from another function.

Comment: Can you paste the actual code because the problem is something else.

Answer (score 1):

There are several things wrong here. First, this is not a self-executing function. This is an object with two functions defined inside it and wrapped in parentheses, which make it invalid. Something like this would be a valid JavaScript object:

```
object1 = {
    function1: function(){
       console.log('function1 called!'); // logs the text 'function1 called!' to the console
},
    function2: function(){
       console.log(this); // logs the details of `object1`
       this.function1();
    }
};
object1.function2();
```

Equivalent functionality using an anonymous function would look something like this:

```
(function (){
    console.log('anonymous function called!');
})();
```

Note the lack of curly brackets surrounding the anonymous function. Unlike the functions in the object, the anonymous function isn't a member of any object. Also note the last set of parentheses at the end, those are what triggers the execution of the anonymous function that has just been defined.

JavaScript functions: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions

Comment: Not possible, I explicitly mentioned that it didn't work

Comment: Updated my answer with a lot more info. Hopefully it's clearer now.